# Jquery Load specific div make button not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

get a problem with after success ajax and load the div. 
Here's the code:

```
 <script>

$('.delete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (confirm('Delete this user?') == true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {_method: "DELETE"},
            url: 'manage-staff-roles/' + id, //resource
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.loader-wrap').removeClass('hiding hide');
            },
            success: function() {
                $('.loader-wrap').addClass('hiding hide');
                $('#table').load(location.href + " #table");
                Messenger().post({
                    message: 'Success.',
                    type: 'success',
                    showCloseButton: true
                });

            }

        });
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
});

</script>
```

---

Here is my html:

```
       <div id="table">
          @foreach($staffroles as $staffrole)

                            {{ $staffrole->id }}

                            {{ $staffrole->name }}

                            <a class="edit" id="staffroles/{{ $staffrole->id }}/edit" href="manage-staff-roles/{{ $staffrole->id }}/edit">
                                Edit </a>
                            |
                            <a class="delete btn" id="{{ $staffrole->id }}" >
                                Delete </a>

                @endforeach
                </div>
```

after the ajax success and do all the function perfectly (including reload the specific div). But the problem is my div that contain a delete button is become unusable but the edit button is working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add click handler using `.on()` for dynamically created buttons. Modify your delete button click handler as shown below

```
$(document).on('click','.delete',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (confirm('Delete this user?') == true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {_method: "DELETE"},
            url: 'manage-staff-roles/' + id, //resource
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.loader-wrap').removeClass('hiding hide');
            },
            success: function() {
                $('.loader-wrap').addClass('hiding hide');
                $('#table').load(location.href + " #table");
                Messenger().post({
                    message: 'Success.',
                    type: 'success',
                    showCloseButton: true
                });

            }

        });
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `.load` method of jQuery, will add new html and this will override any event handlers that were added previously, you will need to re-add the event handlers for button (in case it is overriden by `.load`) so as to continue being re-usable.

Another alternative is to add the event handlers (for button) on parent element and delegate (via [`jQuery.on` method with selector](https://api.jquery.com/on/))

Hope this helps, comment for further info if needed

Comment: yap! thanks for your suggestion next will keep using on.